# On Redisson Java client how can I use and OR operation to fetch by 2 glob patterns?

Tags: redis, glob, redisson

I've got a Hash map of Redis stored, the key is id(Seperator)name(Seperator)othername
how can I get values by the pattern, using 2 potential patterns?
For example I have in the DB the keys:
1(Seperator)name1(Seperator)othername1
2(Seperator)name2(Seperator)othername2
the pattern to get by name would be: *(Seperator)name1(Seperator)*
And I want to get by name using multiple names like : *(Seperator)name1|name2(Seperator)*
but it does not work on Redis glob patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Checked it and it is not possible to do so.
Glob Pattern only allows something like [ab][cde]* which will make and aORb and cORdORe, it can't be used for a whole string.